# Add action event handler to text field java fx

Tags: java, javafx

I have a Textfield node as such in my java fx code:

```
TextField Name= new TextField();
```

I understand how to fire code if one clicks on a button by adding an event handler like so:

```
Button getName= new Button("Save");

getName.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    public void handle(ActionEvent args) {
       System.out.println("You clicked me!"):
    }
});
```

Could I add the same code to my **textField** node so when one clicks on the text field, it fires a bunch of code? Or how do you do this?

Comment: Just as an FYI, an [onAction event handler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextField.html#onActionProperty) can be specified for a TextField.  "The action handler is normally called when the user types the ENTER key."  Which does not appear to be what you are actually asking for.

Comment: So you can specify it for a click?

Comment: No, that is not how `onAction` works for a TextField, for a TextField `onAction` is triggered by the ENTER key, not a click.  If you want to capture a click (or touch) event, you will need an event filter, sry I don't have time write now to type up a solution.

Comment: Ok but thanks, good to know

Comment: Read up on [event handling and event filters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/events.htm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To respond to mouse clicks, use [`setOnMouseClicked`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setOnMouseClicked-javafx.event.EventHandler-).

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ClickOnTextField extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            System.out.println("Clicked");
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane(textField);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 350, 120);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);;
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought that the TextField would consume the mouse click event and it wouldn't bubble back up again to the onMouseClicked handler, so you would need a filter . . . but I thought wrong :-)

Comment: There doesn't seem to be much consistency in when controls consume events and when they don't. IIRC text controls consume key pressed events, but it seems they don't consume mouse events.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
TextField yourTextField = new TextField();
yourTextField.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>()
{
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, Boolean oldPropertyValue, Boolean newPropertyValue)
    {
        if (newPropertyValue)
        {
            System.out.println("Textfield on focus");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Textfield out focus");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: That responds to the text field getting focus, not to a mouse click on it. So, for example, your handler would be fired if the user used the tab key to put focus on the text field (but never used the mouse at all). On the other hand, if the text field already had focus, and the user clicked on it, your handler would not be fired.

Comment: How do I add click event to a text field, really looking for it